# Can I check in at Schipol if I don't have my Thalys train ticket stamped?

Tags: trains, thalys

I had a train ticket from Antwerp Central to Schipol Airport on Thalys in the evening, connecting to a KLM flight from Amsterdam to Mumbai, operated by Jet Airways the next day.

I collected the ticket in the morning but have missed the Thalys.
As my flight is the next day I'm thinking of catching a train tomorrow and going to Schipol.

Will they let me check in?